# How to fix this ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 3, 3, 16) are incompatible in VGG16

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I currently fine-tuning a VGG16 on a multi-classification problem. The requirement is to add a new 1 Conv block, 1 Maxpool layer, 2 FC layers, and an output layer. I have removed the top layers of VGG16.

THIS IS WHAT I WANT (INPUT-->VGG16 without Top Layers(FC) -->Conv Layer --> Maxpool layer --> 2FC layer --> Output Layer).

But when I fit the model using fit_generator, I get this error ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, 3, 3, 16) are incompatible.

HERE IS THE CODE

```
img_size = [224,224]
model = VGG16(input_shape=img_size + [3],weights="imagenet",include_top=False)

Here is the code for fine-tunning:-
# Adding custome layers
x = model.output
x = Conv2D(512,(3,3),padding="same",activation="relu")(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2))(x)
x = Dense(256,activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(128,activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(16,activation="softmax")(x)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
final_model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=predictions)

#Compiling the model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 
final_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.000001),loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])

#Image Augmentation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen_for_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.25)

train_data =  datagen_for_train.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=data,
    directory="/content/rvl-cdip/data_final",
    x_col="path",
    y_col="label",
    batch_size=32,
    subset="training",
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(224,224)
)

validation_data = datagen_for_train.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=data,
    directory="/content/rvl-cdip/data_final",
    x_col="path",
    y_col="label",
    batch_size=32,
    subset="validation",
    class_mode="categorical",
    target_size=(224,224)
)
#Fitting the model
vgg16_1st_model = final_model.fit_generator(
    train_data,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_data),
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    validation_steps=len(validation_data),
    callbacks=[reduce_learning_rate,save_model,tensorBoard]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `x = Flatten()(x)` between your last Dense layer and the `predicitions` layer, to make the shapes correct.

Comment: I already know that I could fix this by adding a Flatten layer.But if I do this then it will be going to change the architecture as My requirement is this  (INPUT-->VGG16 without Top Layers(FC) -->Conv Layer --> Maxpool layer --> 2FC layer --> Output Layer). Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: There is no way around adding a flatten layer. Since it doesn't have any weight it will not change your data in any way, so your requirements should still be fullfilled.